# How to use sqlplus to connect to an Oracle Database located on another host without modifying my own tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, connections, tnsnames

I want to connect to an oracle database located on another host using sqlplus. [This page](http://thomas.eibner.dk/oracle/sqlplus/) suggested adding an item on my tnsnames to connect to that database

```
local_SID =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= hostname.network)(Port= 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = remote_SID))
  )
```

and then use that in sqlplus

```
sqlplus user/pass@local_SID
```

However, in my circumstances modifying the local tnsnames is not possible. Is it possible to connect to a remote database just by using sqlplus argument without having to change tnsnames? Something like

```
sqlplus user/pass@remote_SID@hostname.network ;( I know, this one is not valid)
```

Comment: even shorter - sqlplus userid/password@database

Comment: @GlennLong - but in your version, `database` is still a TNS alias, which has to exist in the `tnsnames.ora`, so it's the same as Louis was trying to avoid?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
 sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))
```

Maybe, and this might depend on the command line environment you're using, you need to quote the string, something like

```
 sqlplus "user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))"
```

or

```
 sqlplus 'user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))'
```

Comment: if using a portable database, use this instead of sid : `(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=remote_service_name))`

Comment: If the password has special characters in it, you may need to quote it. e.g. `'user/"pass"@...' `

Answer (score 40):

You can use [easy connect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/naming.htm#NETAG255) for this:

```
sqlplus usr/pass@hostname.network/remote_service_name
```

To enable *easy connect* on your machine, you need to add it to the `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH`  in sqlnet.ora, e.g.:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(EZCONNECT)
```

If your listener is on a non-default port use `...@hostname.network:port/...`.

Actually it seems you have to supply a service name, not a SID; they may be the same but if not you'll need to obtain that from the server.

Comment: If the service name is the same as the hostname, you don't even need to specify the service name when connecting. (Practically nobody does this, but it's nice to know.)

Comment: Dead link.......

Answer (score 22):

Create a copy of the tnsnames.ora file in a directory that you can write to, modify the file accordingly, then set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the location of that directory.

eg:

```
cp $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora /tmp/tnsnames.ora
# edit the /tmp/tnsnames.ora file to add your entries

# Set the $TNS_ADMIN environment variable so that sqlplus knows where to look 
export TNS_ADMIN=/tmp
```

Comment: This approach works with a system that has no oracle infrastructure installed other than a sqlplus client.  Just copy over the tnsnames.ora from the db server, and follow Phil's process.

Answer (score 5):

On Unix/Linux system you can use the [user level configuration files](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/cnfg_net_srv.htm#UNXAR177) to override system level entries.

```
System-Level         User-Level 
Configuration File   Configuration File
------------------   -------------------
sqlnet.ora           $HOME/.sqlnet.ora
tnsnames.ora         $HOME/.tnsnames.ora
```

The system-level configuration Files can be found in the directory `$TNS_ADMIN` . If the variable `TNS_ADMIN` is not  set then they are searched in the directory `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`.

The user-level configuration files don't substitute the system level configuration files  as a whole (as the `TNS_ADMIN` directory  substitute the whole `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` directory)  but they add to or change entries of the system-level configuration files. If an entry exists in an user-level configuration file then this one is used, if it does not exist in the user-level configuration file then the entry of the system-level configuration file is used.